# Как сложить первые три числа, введенных пользователем?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мой код выводит три числа, без их суммы.

```
nums = input("Введите число: ")
int(nums)
lab = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]
print(lab)
```

Comment: у int  нет [0] и тд. а у строки есть. можно у строки взять [0] патом перевести в инт и после сложить

Comment: ```nums = input().split()``` тогда можно по индекса брать

Comment: Строка int(nums)  у вас делает совсем не то, что вам кажется. Она вообще у вас ничего не делает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Попробуйте так:

Строка, которую ввел пользователь разбивается методом `.split()`, после чего обрезаются ненужные пробелы методом `.strip()` (На самом деле все немного по другому, но это не важно), затем цикл пробегает по тому, что осталось (числа, или символы) и передает каждый елемент функции `int()`, которая в свою очередь передает каждый результат в список, а конструкция `try` обрабатывает случаи, когда введено не число:

```
try:
    nums = [int(n) for n in input('Введите числа: ').strip().split()]
except ValueError:
    print("Ошибка. Вводите пожалуйста только числа")
lab = sum(nums) # Воспользовался встроеной функцией суммы
print(lab)
```

P.S.: int(nums) Возвращает число. Все объекты, на которые нет ссылки - добыча сборщика мусора:

```
#Ваш код:
nums = input("Введите число: ")
int(nums) # <- Будет съедено сборщиком мусора
lab = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]
print(lab)
```